# Instruments shows no leaks or orphaned objects, but app memory grows and levels off on subsequent runs

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, memory-management, memory-leaks

I'm using XCode 8.0; Swift 3.0.  I'm writing a macOS app which creates an array of objects, where each object has a property which is a large array of `[Int]` (That is, an array of arrays of `Int`).  Each object in the array is passed to a separate thread for some mathematical operations.  Here's what the class definition looks like:

```
class SearchBot {

private let BLOCKSCALE = 0.05 // Report progress for each 5%
private var head, start, end, index, size, blockSize : Int
private var doneLoading : Bool
var blocksChunked : Int
var listArray : [[Int]]

init (beginningHere b : Int, andEndingHere e : Int) {

    head = b
    start = b
    end = e
    size = end - start + 1
    listArray = Array<[Int]>(repeating: [0,0], count: size)
    index = 0
    blockSize = Int(Double(size) * BLOCKSCALE)
    blocksChunked = 0
    doneLoading = false

}
```

After creating an array of the SearchBots, with the size of the listArrays in each one being ~1 Million entries, I publish some results.  The program works exactly how I intend and after running:

- Instruments shows no leaks
- Instruments shows no allocation anomalies and snapshotting a generation at program start; running several scenarios; snapshotting at program completion shows now unusual memory growth
- XCode's memory graph shows no orphans and no leaks

but....

XCode's memory indicator (shown below) indicates the program grows from ~20MB at program start to ~211MB after a few runs.  The strange thing is it just stays ~211MB.  It peaks slightly during subsequent runs, but falls back to a new "floor" of 211MB when they're complete.  I observe the same thing in Activity Monitor, even when I archive the program to a binary and run it from there.

**Memory Gauge in XCode**

[image: Memory Gauge in XCode]

I don't think I'm capturing `self` in the closure when I dispatch each array element to a separate thread (it's not showing in the memory graph), but I tried `[unowned self] in` in the closure just in case, and the results were the same with or without it.

I read somewhere that in the ARC world of later versions of OS X (macOS), the system will actually hold-on to deallocated memory from an app (sorta cache it) on the assumption that your program may want it back on subsequent runs.  It only truly releases it when memory starts getting under pressure.

Is that what's going on?

Thanks so much!

Comment: There's clearly not enough here for us to possibly diagnose what's going on. We cannot comment on your conclusion that there are no "allocation anomalies" nor "orphans" nor "leaks" without knowing how you came to those conclusions (frequently, people draw incorrect inferences, though I'm not saying you are). Having said that, the general behavior sounds a lot like cached memory (though there's nothing like that in your code snippet). Re your closing paragraph about how it hangs on to memory, no, your allocations and memory gauge behavior are not attributable to anything like that.

Comment: Thanks very much for taking the time to read through this.  The tip about the memory gauge is really helpful.  Apologize for my lack of detail in the posting, which I take as a sign that I have a lot to learn.  I'm going to drop back and use a stripped-down version of my program and build it up in stages, testing memory issues along the way (should have started there).  I'm sure I'm reading the memory graph and/or instruments incorrectly and the answer is probably staring me in the face.  I'm sure the journey will make me stronger :-)  Thanks again!

Comment: BTW, the WWDC videos are pretty good. [Fixing Memory Issues](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2013/410/) is good overall discussion. For discussion on newer Debug Memory Graph feature, see latter part of [Visual Debugging with Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/410/). The first video, while dated, has a much better description of the broader array of memory issues, though.

Comment: Fantastic videos.  Thanks!